# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused when deploying a laravel app to Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, heroku

I’m trying to deploy a laravel app to heroku. I’ve succesfully done so already with one of my apps, but here I get the following error when running the command heroku run php artisan migrate:

```
In Connection.php line 664:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from 
information_schema.tables where table_schema = todolist and 
table_name = migrations)

In Connector.php line 67:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I have checked that database.php and .env have matching configurations:

.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=foo.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=database
DB_USERNAME=user    
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

database.php:

```
return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),

      'connections' => [


        'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'foo.amazonaws.com'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'user'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'password'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ]

]
```

I have read some similar posts and tried changing DB_HOST from 127.0.0.1 to localhost but it didn’t work.

The database values were given by heroku after I used postgres for my database. Am I missing anything here? All advice is welcome.

Comment: I hope these aren't your actual database name, username, passwords. I would edit to post to hide these, and then change your database credentials.

Answer (score 5):

The .env file is ignored by git, so that won’t be pushed to Heroku. To solve your problem, the credentials should be in the database.php file the same way you have them:

```
'pgsql' => [
      'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'ec2-12-34-56-789.compute-1.amazonaws.com'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'dbXXXXXXXXXXXX'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ]
```

The password should be 64 characters long, so I would say maybe double check the values and then push the changes again. After a successful push, run:

```
$ heroku run php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Avoid to put your credentials in database.php, because this will be public to other contributors on repository! Instead, configure "Settings -> Config vars" in your app heroku settings