# laravel deploy on heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku

I try to deploy the laravel app on Heroku but I have this issue.
created procfile and I updated the composer but not working.
my SQL is turned on and locally everything works

```
   In Connection.php line 742:
                                                                             
     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `menus`)  
                                                                             
   
   In Connector.php line 70:
                                                
     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
                                                
   
   Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned 
with error code 1
!     WARNING: An error occurred during a database connection or query
!     ERROR: Dependency installation failed!
!     
!     The 'composer install' process failed with an error. The cause
!     may be the download or installation of packages, or a pre- or
!     post-install hook (e.g. a 'post-install-cmd' item in 'scripts')
!     in your 'composer.json'.
!     
!     Typical error cases are out-of-date or missing parts of code,
!     timeouts when making external connections, or memory limits.
!     
!     Check the above error output closely to determine the cause of
!     the problem, ensure the code you're pushing is functioning
!     properly, and that all local changes are committed correctly.
!     
!     For more information on builds for PHP on Heroku, refer to
!     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support
!     
!     REMINDER: the following warnings were emitted during the build;
!     check the details above, as they may be related to this error:
!     - An error occurred during a database connection or query
!     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
!     Push failed
```

Comment: Add your procfile. But the error is basically indicating your database connection is not working. Most likely incorrect database credentials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51086681/sqlstatehy000-2002-connection-refused-when-deploying-a-laravel-app-to-heroku